# Not able to get 4 leading zeros in sha256 hash proof of work- ever (Java)

Tags: java, hash, sha256

I'm build a blockchain app.

When I run tests in main, no matter what I do, no matter how much time I give it, when I log different things out, I'm unable to get 4 leading zeroes and so complete a difficulty level of 4. I see the log of the binary hashes and many times they have repeating elements, 1111 for instance, but never 0000 until my time is hit and the difficulty decreases to three. I have no idea why.

I borrowed the hash algorithm from an online source and I checked its output against an online hasher and it checked out.

I know with each level of difficulty it increases exponentially but 2^4 is still only 16 and I see other repeating numbers (1111, 1010, any combination except 0000). Is there any reason why this might be the case?

I wanted to provide an abundance of code rather than a shortage. Logically it makes no sense why randomly if all numbers were equally possible, it woudln't turn up 0000* (e.g. 0000101011at some point). therefore Four zeros must not be possible, but why? I waited 100 seconds mutliple times and saw other numbers repeat themselves. I saw it hit at exactly 4 or 3 or 2 seconds each time on the dot when difficulty went to three. When I start at difficulty 5 (genesis block) it will never solve- I'm sure even if I left it running overnight. So what could be going on?

```java
package privblock.gerald.ryan;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date; // gets time in ms.
import privblock.gerald.ryan.util.CryptoHash;

/**
 * 
 * @author Gerald Ryan Block Class of blockchain app
 *
 *         Description: The block hash is the result of the timestamp, the
 *         last_hash, the data, the difficulty and the nonce
 *
 */
public class Block {
    long timestamp;
    String lastHash;
    String hash;
    String[] data;
    int difficulty;
    int nonce;


// Millisecond basis
    ;
    static long MILLISECONDS = 1;
    static long SECONDS = 1000 * MILLISECONDS;
    static long MINE_RATE = 2 * SECONDS;

    /**
     * A block is a unit of storage for a blockchain that supports a cryptocurrency.
     * 
     * @param timestamp
     * @param lastHash
     * @param hash
     * @param data
     * @param difficulty
     * @param nonce
     */
    public Block(long timestamp, String lastHash, String hash, String[] data, int difficulty, int nonce) {
        super();
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.lastHash = lastHash;
        this.hash = hash;
        this.data = data;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.nonce = nonce;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n-----------BLOCK--------\ntimestamp: " + this.timestamp + "\nlastHash: " + this.lastHash + "\nhash: "
                + this.hash + "\ndifficulty: " + this.getDifficulty() + "\nNonce: " + this.nonce
                + "\n-----------------------\n";
    }

    /**
     * Mine a block based on given last block and data until a block hash is found
     * that meets the leading 0's Proof of Work requirement.
     * 
     * @param last_block
     * @param data
     * @return
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    public static Block mine_block(Block last_block, String[] data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        String last_hash = last_block.getHash();
        int difficulty = Block.adjust_difficulty(last_block, timestamp);
        int nonce = 0;
        String hash = CryptoHash.getSHA256(timestamp, last_block.getHash(), data, difficulty, nonce);

        String proof_of_work = CryptoHash.n_len_string('0', difficulty);
//      System.out.println("Proof of work " + proof_of_work);
        String binary_hash = CryptoHash.hex_to_binary(hash);
//      System.out.println("binary hash " + binary_hash);
        String binary_hash_work_end = binary_hash.substring(0, difficulty);
//      System.out.println("binary_Hash_work_end " + binary_hash_work_end);
        System.out.println("Difficulty: " + difficulty);
        while (!proof_of_work.equalsIgnoreCase(binary_hash_work_end)) {
//          System.out.println("Working");
            nonce += 1;
            timestamp = new Date().getTime();
            difficulty = Block.adjust_difficulty(last_block, timestamp);
            hash = CryptoHash.getSHA256(timestamp, last_block.getHash(), data, difficulty, nonce);

            proof_of_work = CryptoHash.n_len_string('0', difficulty);
            binary_hash = CryptoHash.hex_to_binary(hash);
            binary_hash_work_end = binary_hash.substring(0, difficulty);
//          System.out.println(binary_hash_work_end);
//          System.out.println(binary_hash);
//          System.out.println(proof_of_work);
        }
        System.out.println("Solved at Difficulty: " + difficulty);
//      System.out.println("Proof of work requirement " + proof_of_work);
//      System.out.println("binary_Hash_work_end " + binary_hash_work_end);
//      System.out.println("binary hash " + binary_hash);
        System.out.println("BLOCK MINED");

        return new Block(timestamp, last_hash, hash, data, difficulty, nonce);
    }

    /**
     * Generate Genesis block
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static Block genesis_block() {
        long timestamp = 1;
        String last_hash = "genesis_last_hash";
        String hash = "genesis_hash";
        String[] data = { "buy", "privcoin" };
        int difficulty = 4;
        int nonce = 0;
        return new Block(timestamp, last_hash, hash, data, difficulty, nonce);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the adjusted difficulty according to the MINE_RATE. Increase the
     * difficulty for quickly mined blocks. Decrease the difficulty for slowly mined
     * blocks.
     * 
     * @param last_block
     * @param new_timestamp
     */
    public static int adjust_difficulty(Block last_block, long new_timestamp) {
        long time_diff = new_timestamp - last_block.getTimestamp();

//      System.out.println(time_diff);
        if (time_diff < MINE_RATE) {
//          System.out.println("Increasing difficulty");
            return last_block.getDifficulty() + 1;
        } else if (last_block.getDifficulty() - 1 > 0) {
//          System.out.println("Decreasing difficulty");
            return last_block.getDifficulty() - 1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate block by enforcing following rules: - Block must have the proper
     * last_hash reference - Block must meet the proof of work requirements -
     * difficulty must only adjust by one - block hash must be a valid combination
     * of block fields
     * 
     * @param last_block
     * @param block
     * @return
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    public static boolean is_valid_block(Block last_block, Block block) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String binary_hash = CryptoHash.hex_to_binary(block.getHash());
        char[] pow_array = CryptoHash.n_len_array('0', block.getDifficulty());
        char[] binary_char_array = CryptoHash.string_to_charray(binary_hash);
        if (!block.getLastHash().equalsIgnoreCase(last_block.getHash())) {
            System.out.println("The last hash must be correct");
            return false;
            // Throw exception the last hash must be correct
        }
        if (!Arrays.equals(pow_array, Arrays.copyOfRange(binary_char_array, 0, block.getDifficulty()))) {
            System.out.println("Proof of work requirement not met");
            return false;
            // throw exception - proof of work requirement not met
        }
        if (Math.abs(last_block.difficulty - block.difficulty) > 1) {
            System.out.println("Block difficulty must adjust by one");
            return false;
            // throw exception: The block difficulty must only adjust by 1
        }
        String reconstructed_hash = CryptoHash.getSHA256(block.getTimestamp(), block.getLastHash(), block.getData(),
                block.getDifficulty(), block.getNonce());
        if (!block.getHash().equalsIgnoreCase(reconstructed_hash)) {
            System.out.println("The block hash must be correct");
            System.out.println(block.getHash());
            System.out.println(reconstructed_hash);
            return false;
            // throw exception: the block hash must be correct
        }
        System.out.println("You have mined a valid block");
        return true;
    }

    public int getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public String getLastHash() {
        return lastHash;
    }

    public String[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public int getNonce() {
        return nonce;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
//      String md = CryptoHash.getSHA256("foobar");
        Block genesis = genesis_block();
        System.out.println(genesis.toString());
//      Block bad_block = Block.mine_block(genesis, new String[] { "watch", "AOT" });
//      bad_block.lastHash = "evil data";
//      System.out.println(bad_block.toString());
        Block good_block = mine_block(genesis, new String[] { "foo", "bar" });
        System.out.println(good_block.toString());
//      System.out.println(mine_block(new_block, new String[] { "crypto", "is", "fun" }).toString());
//      System.out.println(Block.is_valid_block(genesis, bad_block)); // returns false as expected
        System.out.println(Block.is_valid_block(genesis, good_block));
        System.out.println(CryptoHash.hex_to_binary(good_block.getHash()));
        Block good_block2 = mine_block(good_block, new String[] { "bar", "foo" });
        Block good_block3 = mine_block(good_block2, new String[] { "bar", "foo" });
        Block good_block4 = mine_block(good_block3, new String[] { "bar", "foo" });
//      Block good_block5 = mine_block(good_block4, new String[] {"bar", "foo"});
//      Block good_block6 = mine_block(good_block5, new String[] {"bar", "foo"});
    }

}
```

```java
package privblock.gerald.ryan.util;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CryptoHash {
    static HashMap<Character, String> HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE;
    static {
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('0', "0000");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('1', "0001");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('2', "0010");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('3', "0011");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('4', "0100");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('5', "0101");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('6', "0110");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('7', "0111");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('8', "1000");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('9', "1001");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('a', "1010");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('b', "1011");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('c', "1100");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('d', "1101");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('e', "1110");
        HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.put('f', "1111");
    }

    public static String getSHA256(String... sarray) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String s = concat(sarray);
//      System.out.printf("Hashing \"%s\"\n", s);
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] b = md.digest(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, b);
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(number.toString(16));
        while (hexString.length() < 32) {
            hexString.insert(0, '0');
        }
        String mds = hexString.toString();
//      System.out.printf("hash is:\n%s\n", mds);
        return hexString.toString();

    }

    public static String getSHA256(long timestamp, String last_hash, String[] data, int difficulty, int nonce)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String s = "";

        s += Long.toString(timestamp);
        s += last_hash;
        s += concat(data);
        s += Integer.toString(difficulty);
        s += Integer.toString(nonce);
//      System.out.printf("Hashing \"%s\"\n", s);
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] b = md.digest(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, b);
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(number.toString(16));
//      System.out.println(hexString);
        while (hexString.length() < 32) {
            hexString.insert(0, '0');
        }
        String messageDigestString = hexString.toString();
//      System.out.printf("hash is:\n%s\n", messageDigestString);
        return hexString.toString();
    }
    
    public static char[] n_len_array(char c, int n) {
        char[] ch = new char[n];
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            ch[i] = c;
        }
        return ch;
    }
    
    public static String n_len_string(char c, int n) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            s += c;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static String concat(String... args) {
        String s = "";
        for (String $ : args) {
            s += $;
        }
//      System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }

    public static char[] string_to_charray(String str) {
        char[] ch = new char[str.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            ch[i] = str.charAt(i);
        }
        return ch;
    }

    public static String string_to_hex(String arg) {
        return String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }

    public static String hex_to_binary(String hex_string) {
        String binary_string = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < hex_string.length(); i++) {
            binary_string += HEX_TO_BIN_TABLE.get(hex_string.charAt(i));
        }
        return binary_string;
    }

    public static String string_to_binary(String raw_string) {
        String hex_string = string_to_hex(raw_string);
        String bin_string = hex_to_binary(hex_string);
        return bin_string;
    }
    


}
```

ps here's an example of a log I created. I created other cleaner logs too but this shows what we're working with. The first item represents time in milliseconds. The second represents the first four digits of the hash, which is directly below it, followed by the level of difficulty requirement string (what the second item needs to be, length n = difficulty level). The hash just never leads with four zeros, ever, so my hash function or call to the function must be broken in some way.

```
6479
1000
1000001010111011100110111010100100111010101001111110010101011101101101110000110100110110110000001010001000000010110001100111100111010100110001001001110111011010011100110000011111110100000100000100000010100001000110000111000101100010001111011000110011111101
0000
6479
0101
0101110111010100101010100000001011100011000001110001011011001101001111101011010011000111101101111111001001001010100110101101100111111011001011100101111000011100010001000000000011000111010000101101001000001010101010111001010000101001110011111101011011011000
0000
6479
1000
1000000001000101001110001110110000110111001101100001011000111010111110001011011010011111111101011001110011001001111011011110110010101010101100011011001001110001100010010101001011100001101011011101010000000100111100011011110100000101100111010100100110011101
0000
6479
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. It is indeed often returning 4 leading zeroes but the code as structured is clipping them off (because it doesn't think they have meaning). I noticed by logging that the length is not always a fixed 64byte/256 bit string. Here's the output:

```
256
1101111000010000100001110001010001010000001010111001100011010011110010001001010001010010100110111000110010000010001110110100100101000000001111111110011100000001010100000111001000111101010001010100110100000000111000100001000000010010010111011110110011110111
256
011001111101001000011111011001111110010110000011001011111010001011010110010100001011010011010010111101100010010111000010110010110111110001010101100000000101001000111110100111011100001110010010101011011000000101100001101110101101010001110000111111110000
252
0001100101110011101000000011000101011100111101110100111110100101110110011100010110001011000110010011110110011001100111010001100100011001011000001011100011011011011011101000111000011100100011011011011000101010011101000110101011000110011100111010000011000011
256
1100110001001001110001100111100010101100100010110111100111001010011011111111100010100110110000010000101000010111111010010101110001100010101010111111111111001011010111010100001010000010111100100100111000010101011000110000100000100111010001000011000000010000
256
```

So that's solved, or at least I understand the problem. It's amazing what sleep will do.